# posting AJAX call to http url from both HTTP and HTTPS pages

Tags: ajax, http, https

I have to integrate a 3rd party newsletter signup form that makes an AJAX call to HTTP url.

That form I'm placing on pages that use HTTP or HTTPS protocols ( http for home pg., ect.; https for ecommerce related stuff )

I don't think anything is sent back from the destination server ( at least I can't see the response) other than status code.

I'm getting **200 OK** whether I submit the form from HTTP or HTTPS page and watch what's going on with it in Firebug. Wonder if it's safe to assume the call gets processed successfully?

Usually, I like to have a proof positive that something worked or didn't, but in this case all test signups show up the next day, ( due to sign up getting processed as some scheduled task I'm guessing ), hence the unease.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window.location.protocol to check whether you're currently on a Secure connection, and if so, you should AJAX a secure url.

Comment: ... alter the protocol part of the url used in the AJAX call? I thought about doing that, but will the destination server care about the protocol used by in the url?

Comment: It might, but it should be fairly simple. If you can visit the https: version of the page you're AJAX'ing in a browser, then you can AJAX it, so you need to test it and make sure it's secure.

Comment: ... just did both and got 'success' in the browser

Comment: Then you're ready to go. This is how, by the way, Google and other API's do it, so you can look at their Page Tracker for example to see this conditional check.

Answer (score 2):

You can call https server from http but can't call http from https directly using AJAX.

To call http user from https server you need to call your server side application from java script using AJAX, and then call http url from your server side application then send back this to the client.